# simple autoregression AR(1) residuals, in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use simple AR(1) process. I have some 8 values. 
How can i get the residuals of each step?
for example:

```
residuals(ar(AirPassengers,aid = FALSE,order.max = 1,method = "ols"))
```

returns `NULL`.

Comment: @Mateusz1981 This example is reproducible.

Comment: shouldn't it be `aic` instead of `aid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, e.g., `ar(AirPassengers, aid = FALSE, order.max = 1, method = "ols")$resid`. That is, instead of applying functions `resid` or `residuals`, you should check the element `resid` that `ar` returns.

Comment: @EranZwilling, then accepting the answer and perhaps upvoting it would be appropriate.

Comment: @Julius, thanks again. I just tried to upvote and accept. I hope I did it well... ;)